Nightly scheduled yaml pipeline runs even though there are no changes after a manual run
We have a nightly pipeline that runs to build our application, setup with a schedule like this:
schedules:
- cron: '0 0 * * *'
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: false

This is all works fine and is only built when any changes actually go in. This is the build our SQA team pick up the next day all is well.
The problem comes when it is more of an urgent build, whereby we manually trigger a build so it can be tested the same day. The pipeline still runs again that night, even though there are no changes to the branch. This leads to a bit of confusion to SQA, as well as a bit of a waste of resources. There is a new build with no changes to those that have previously been tested. There are no work items associated to this second run, so it seems like it should be able to know whether there are actually any changes.
How can this be changed to not run if there aren't actually any changes since it's last run?

The keyword here is scheduled.
always: boolean # whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run. The default is false.

I'd consider diving into why you need a "more urgent build". Is it an urgent feature release or a bug fix - and then use a branch strategy / pipeline filter to support that reason.
Alternatively, you could write a script that does a git diff between HEAD and HEAD~1
git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runJob]true"
else
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runJob]false"
fi

Then you add a condition: eq(variables.runJob, 'true')
But please don't do that. It's ugly and brittle and is butchering your pipeline.

Thanks @pete-msft, I understand the definition of that bool, that is why I haven't tried to raise a bug.
I agree I don't want to put in some ugly/brittle code but at the moment it seems a better solution than the current problem.
Yes the case is that I am doing a hotfix to a release candidate build, where it is beneficial to get these changes in right away rather than wait for it to run at night. 95% of the time that urgency is not there. It would be inefficient use of resources to always do this.
I might be missing something, but I don't understand the current behaviour is useful.

The other reason we do this, is when the nightly failed for whatever reason (UI test failed or server problem as ours run on self hosted agents). And we manually run it again and if no code goes in that day, we get this extra run again.
This pipeline always has this scheduled code in it, but it's not as though I can't run it manually also.
Ideally the branch is always release ready, and SQA does this on the PR but we are not there yet. I don't understand what branch/strategy would help but have the same issue in a different form.

Because the branch separates the concerns. You have a main branch for regular releases. When you create a hotfix, you branch the main - prepare the hotfix. When you commit the hotfix, the pipeline triggers on the branch and creates a hotfix package. Then you pass the hotfix package to your testers.

This means that you're being explicit about what you're doing and removes the confusion about what's in the package. ie - if it comes from hotfix-132 then it's REALLY clear to testers what they're testing. Your branching strategy formalises your communication.

"Ideally the branch is always release ready" - this is a wish. Good intentions don't work - you need a mechanism. You talk about inefficient use of resources to do this, yet in your original question you state "This leads to a bit of confusion to SQA, as well as a bit of a waste of resources." - so which inefficiency do you want? I can't answer that because I don't know your business as well as you do.

I am essentially doing all of this, I don't follow how this would help the scenario. What would really perfect the workflow if this pipeline didn't just build again. There is no explanation why that is ever beneficial.

Just strictly on a pipeline basis ignoring what branches are going on etc. I have a nightly pipeline that only builds if code has gone in since it's last run. Somebody manually triggers the build, it builds a nightly release early. The schedule for this pipeline builds again later.... Why? Why would it?
Was it easier to implement this way? Is that the most user friendly? I don't believe things should be so inflexible, there are always different reasons why the normal process is slightly changed here and there.

I bet there are loads of people out there that just ignore a build in this occasion. And not so much of a perfectionist as me, who would rather it didn't just do it for no reason in those rare occassions.

"What would really perfect the workflow if this pipeline didn't just build again." - I've already told you how to do this, you just don't like the answer. It's beneficial because then you're not mixing concerns.

"I bet there are loads of people out there that just ignore a build in this occasion." - then do that and move on. You're not a perfectionist. If you were, you'd separate the build concerns into nightly scheduled builds and hotfix builds - like I explained.

"ust strictly on a pipeline basis ignoring what branches are going on etc." No. Branches and pipelines support each other. There IS no ignoring what branches are going on. It's like ignoring the power of the engine when putting the brakes on a car.

As Pete has mentioned, this behavior is expected, because schedules: cron: always: false is designed to run the pipeline only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run.
For this, you may consider adding a Check job to your pipeline, which can filter this pipeline's succeeded builds using the same code version as that the schedule run and decide whether to skip the downstream job(s). Here is my sample YAML pipeline for your reference, whose PowerShell script uses this API to list and filter all builds history of the current pipeline.
schedules:
- cron: '0/5 * * * *'
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: false


jobs:
- job: Check
  steps:
  - powershell: |
     
      # Authenticate against the System.AccessToken of the pipeline service account
      $headers = @{
          'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + '$(System.AccessToken)'
          'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
      }
      $URL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$(System.DefinitionId)&api-version=7.1-preview.7"
      $buildsByDefinition = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $URL -Headers $headers

      # Filter the builds based on sourceVersion
      $matchingBuilds = $buildsByDefinition.value | Where-Object { $_.sourceVersion -eq "$(Build.SourceVersion)" }

      # Check if any of the matching builds have a successful result
      $anySucceeded = $matchingBuilds | Where-Object { $_.result -eq "succeeded" }

      if ($anySucceeded) {
          Write-Host "At least one build with sourceVersion $(Build.SourceVersion) succeeded."
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SkipSchedule;isoutput=true]true"
      } else {
          Write-Host "No successful builds found for the specified sourceVersion $(Build.SourceVersion)."
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SkipSchedule;isoutput=true]false"
      }
    name: CheckIfSkipSchedule

- job: Downstream
  dependsOn: Check
  condition: or(
      ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'),
      eq(dependencies.Check.outputs['CheckIfSkipSchedule.SkipSchedule'], 'false')
    )
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Downstream steps start"
    displayName: Downstream steps



